# Call Python File from MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, call, permission-denied, bin

I am trying to call a Python function from MATLAB, and I'm getting a permission denied error.

```
function [success] = run python()
%system('sudo easy_install requests');
%system('sudo easy_install PyCrypto');
system('/Users/mmk/Desktop/Folder/run.py')

success = 1;

end
```

The error is:

```
/bin/bash: /Users/mmk/Desktop/Folder/run.py: Permission denied

ans =

    1
```

Not sure what I should be doing in this case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out.

it needs to be system('**python** /Users/mmk/Desktop/Folder/run.py')

Comment: Alternatively, if your python file is executable (google chmod), and you make the first line of the file `#!/usr/bin/env python` your previous approach should have worked, too.